# How to add a method to a button to switch between scenes in JavaFX

Tags: java, button, javafx

I have created two java classes which have a static method which returns an AnchorPane after setting all properties of required labels and buttons.
For example:

```
class HomePageScene {
    static AnchorPane getHomePageScene() {
        //some code
        //a button which is to be clicked to go to Login Page
        //some code
    }
}

class LoginPageScene {
    static AnchorPane getLoginPageScene() {
        //some code
    }
}
```

And there is another class which has the `main()`.

```
public class JavaFXEventDemo extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage myStage) {
        myStage.setTitle("Program Windiw");
        AnchorPane HomePane = HomePageScene.getHomePageScene();
        AnchorPane LoginPane = LoginPageScene.getLoginPageScene();

        Scene HomePage = new Scene(HomePane, 400.0, 300.0);
        Scene LoginPage = new Scene(LoginPane, 400.0, 300.0);

        myStage.setScene(HomePage);
        myStage.show();
    }
}
```

First I set the HomePage as the scene on the stage. In the screen there is a button, which when I click, I want the scene to the LoginPage. How do I do this?
All the three classes are in different files.I tried setting onAction() method, but in that, handle() method's return type is void, whereas I need to return an AnchorPane.

Comment: totally not clear, what you want to do. Can you elaborate your problem in greater detail?

Comment: I added more information, hope it helps more

Answer (score 2):

Bind a function for your button (onAction). In this function, call a function in your main class which will load the scene you want (void javafx.scene.Scene.setRoot(Parent value)) ?

---

EDIT:

What I meant :

```
public class JavaFXEventDemo extends Application {

    private static Scene HomePage;
    private static Scene LoginPage;
    private static Stage myStage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage myStage) {
        JavaFXEventDemo.myStage = myStage;
        myStage.setTitle("Program Windiw");

        AnchorPane HomePane = HomePageScene.getHomePageScene();
        AnchorPane LoginPane = LoginPageScene.getLoginPageScene();

        HomePage = new Scene(HomePane, 400.0, 300.0);
        LoginPage = new Scene(LoginPane, 400.0, 300.0);

        loadHomePage();
        myStage.show();
    }

    public static void loadHomePage(){
        JavaFXEventDemo.myStage.setScene(HomePage);
    }

    public static void loadLoginPage(){
        JavaFXEventDemo.myStage.setScene(LoginPage);
    }
}
```

And just call loadXXXXPage() on your button.

Comment: The problem is that I have two different files for each scene. I had tried what you said, but the in onAction, handle() method's return type is void, whereas I need to return an AnchorPane. I added some more information, could you see it again?